# Questions greyed out in overview

Tags: support, user-interface

[Note: I've discovered why, now the question is how? See below]

I've noticed in the last few days a number of questions being greyed out, such as the example below. There are no downvotes on them, that I can see.

Is this a bug, or a feature?

I am using Firefox 8.0.

**ETA:** I just realized that I had the regex tag on my "ignore tag" list, where I sure did not put it. It's always been on my favourite list, and before, questions tagged perl + regex have been red/pink. I've no idea how regex ended up on my ignore list.

I guess this changes my question to: *How did "regex" move from my favourite tag list to my ignore tag list?* Not sure if I should edit the question more to reflext this.

[image: As viewed in Firefox 8.0]

Comment: Do you have .net or asp.net ignored too?

Comment: @JNK'sMetAccount I have nothing ignored. Just two favourites, perl + regex.

Comment: [The little star in the tag-popup-window makes it easy to move tags between 'ignore' and 'favorite'](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116300/157556). Perhaps you clicked it by accident?

Comment: @sarnold That could be it. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Those are questions that have tags that you have ignored. They won't appear on your home page, but they will appear in lists of questions (e.g. new questions, tag pages); however, they will be greyed-out to show the presence of an ignored tag.

Comment: Yes, I just realized that I had regex as an ignored tag. That is very, very odd, because I put it under favorite tags, where it's been for a long, long time.

Comment: But, why is it not happening in IE then?  (For the record, it _is_ working for me in IE 8).

Comment: @S.L.Barth I was not logged into SO in IE, haven't used IE in months.

Comment: @S.L.Barth In fact, I was unable to log in... that's odd. Oh well.