# Please let me ignore tags by hovering over them and clicking "ignore"

Tags: feature-request, tags, ignored-tags

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What happened to the ignore option in the mouseover on the tags?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78528/what-happened-to-the-ignore-option-in-the-mouseover-on-the-tags)
>   [Easier way to add a FAVOURITE or IGNORE Tag](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83648/easier-way-to-add-a-favourite-or-ignore-tag)

I have a lot of tags in my ignore list, and I mean a **lot**. It would be cool if I were able to simply click on a tag to ignore it, or maybe use a drag'n'drop action, moving the tag I want to ignore over the ignore list.

I use the ignore list for tags that I do not know anything about and tags that I know I am not going to answer questions for in the near future. Currently, I have to scroll a lot whenever I want to ignore a tag because my ignore list is so big. I do not want to subscribe to tags, because I like to "surf" the many new questions, and the ignore list helps me see only the questions that I know I can contribute to, either by comment or answer.

Comment: And some nice screenshots in [Idea For Ignored Tags](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114124/idea-for-ignored-tags/114126#114126).

Comment: @Arjan ooooh my god :D I have actually tried to hover over, but I looked for a "ignore"-kinda link. I have maybe just found a hidden feature ;) thanks!!

Comment: All credit to the creator [of those screenshots](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114124/idea-for-ignored-tags/114126#114126)! Though aligned horribly ;-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can already do this by clicking twice on the small star on the thing that shows when you hover over a tag.

[image: click twice to ignore]

The first click makes it a favorite, the second ignores it and the third click returns the tag to the default state.

Comment: Thanks! I _never_ would have found that. Never.